# How can i add the CRC property to Zip File wit h 7zip command line tool?

Tags: zip, 7zip, deflate, crc32

I try to reverse engineer a backup routine, because the existing routine is single-threaded and there are no updates coming soon. I want to use existing methods instead of creating new ones, so i tried 7zip command line tool. The backup routing creates more or less a zip file encrypted with AES-256 Deflate and creates a CRC for every file in the archive.

What I tried so far:

```
7za.exe a -mem=AES256 -scrcCRC32 -p backup.zip anyFolder
```

also tried to include the hash with:

```
7za.exe h backup.zip -ir*
```

but i get error: Too SHort Switch: r*

Here you can see a part of the file Info from "7za.exe l -slt backup.zip"

```
...
   Encrypted = +
   CRC = 086A8F3F
   Method = AES-256 Deflate
...
```

My created backup.zip looks like this:

```
...
   Encrypted = +
   CRC =
   Method = AES-256 Deflate
...
```

So I need the CRC to be filled (with CRC32), i dont care if it creates it with the initial command or with a second command. The first results show about 5x faster backup, I look forward for your replies!

Comment: I don't have an answer for this, but I have noticed that this is only an issue with AES encryption.  When ZipCrypto is used for the encryption method the CRC is added automatically.  Also, the `-h` argument does not add the hash to the archive like you are asking, it only prints it out to the terminal.